# Avoiding appending of previous page parameter when clicking on jquery tabs

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, tabs

In my webpage I am using jquery tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

         $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs({
             rotate: false,
             startCollapsed: 'accordion',
             collapsible: 'accordion',
             setHash: true,
             disabled: [3,4],
             activate: function(e, tab) {
                 $('.info').html('Tab <strong>' + tab.id + '</strong> activated!');
             }
         });

         $('#start-rotation').on('click', function() {
             $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('active');
         });
         $('#stop-rotation').on('click', function() {
             $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('stopRotation');
         });
         $('#start-rotation').on('click', function() {
             $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('active');
         });
         $('.select-tab').on('click', function() {
             $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('activate', $(this).val());
         });

    });
</script>
<div id="horizontalTab" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <ul class="tabul">
        <li class="tabli">
            <a href="#purchased"><?php echo lang('purchasedtickets');?></a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabli"><a href="#gifted" onclick="giftedtickets('<?php echo $userid;?>','<?php echo base_url();?>')"><?php echo lang('gifted').' '.lang('tickets');?></a></li>
        <li class="tabli"><a href="#received" onclick="receivedtickets('<?php echo $userid;?>','<?php echo base_url();?>')"><?php echo lang('received').' '.lang('tickets');?></a></li>
     </ul>
     <div id="purchased"></div>
     <div id="gifted"></div>
     <div id="received"></div>
</div>
```

When I click on tab2 ie, *#gifted* tab, the corresponding result will be fetched from an ajax call and will be set to div with id *gifted*. In this sections I am using Codeigniter pagination. If I click on pagination link 2 of gifted section, the URL will come like http://domain.org/project/video/tickets/2#gifted where 2 in the URL is the page number.

After this, when I click on any other tab say tab1 ie, *purchased* tab, then the link of page will come like http://domain.org/project/teshot/video/tickets/2#purchased (instead of http://domain.org/project/teshot/video/tickets#purchased) which is appending the url of previous section.

I want to avoid this problem. How can I solve this?

Can ayone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try doing a reload with that uri or regenerate the html with ajax request for page 1 as it would the the page with initial data.

Comment: How to set page url on clicking the tabs?

Comment: jquery onclick method. just change the location to that uri.